# How to solve codemirror problem for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, android-webview, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I downloaded code mirror from official website and tried to test it on mobile device. At first I linked all the core files as described in the docs.
Inside the index.html I added the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- link codemirror -->
  <script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/duotone-dark.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, 
    {
      mode: "javascript",
      value: "var a = 'DS code is cool thanks to codemirror';",
      lineNumbers: true,
      lineWrapping: true
    }
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried to preview it, It looks it's working properly but it's not.

When I add a new line and try to backpress,
**i.** it hide soft keyboard and Backpress doesn't work when removing new line(see figure 1).

When I type **var** and press enter,
**ii.** it misbehave(see figure 2. It is not working sometimes when I click the editor to edit).

**iii.** It is also not taking the full height of screen.

### Figure 1

[image: Figure 1]

### Figure 2

[image: Figure 2]

How to solve them? Thanks in advance.
My main purpose is to add it inside android webview.

Comment: I have the same problem! OP, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No, I couldn't find any way to resolve this.

Comment: OP, after some testing, I have a hypothesis on what's wrong! I need more information from you though—are you using CodeMirror 5?

Comment: I used code mirror 5.something